# Determinant of $A+A^T$ is an odd integer if $\text{det}(A-A^T)=1$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

Let $A\in\text{Mat}(2n\times 2n;\mathbb{Z})$ be an integer matrix such that $\text{det}(A-A^T)=1$. I want to show that $\text{det}(A+A^T)$ is an odd integer. Murasugi claims in his book "Knot Theory and its Applications" that this is trivial and it probably follows immeditiately from some determinant property of skew-symmetric resp. symmetric matrices. But I just can not proof it. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The point is that, so long as we enforce zeros on the diagonal, then skew-symmetric and symmetric matrices coincide in characteristic 2.

More formally, consider the ring homomorphism $\phi:\mathbb Z\longrightarrow R\cong \mathbb F_2$
then define $\Phi$ to apply $\phi$ component-wise to the matrix $B\in \mathbb Z^{m\times m}$.  Then

$\phi\Big(\det\big(B\big)\Big)=\det\Big(\Phi\big(B\big)\Big)$
and with $B:=A+A^T$ we have
$\phi\Big(\det\big(A+A^T\big)\Big)=\det\Big(\Phi\big(A+A^T\big)\Big)=\det\Big(\Phi\big(A-A^T\big)\Big)=\phi\Big(\det\big(A-A^T\big)\Big)=\phi(1)=1$
so $\det\big(A+A^T\big)\%2 =1$, i.e. the determinant is odd.

Comment: The $\cdot ^T$ in the OP turns out  to be a red herring, i. e., it works with  general $A\pm B$ just as with $A\pm A^T$.

Comment: Just wondering: Where is it used that the order of the matrix is even?

Comment: @MartinR -- it is implied/required in the original problem statement when we are told $\text{det}(A-A^T)=1$ -- the determinant would have to be zero if it was odd order

Comment: @user8675309: Yes, of course. Thanks.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen -- This is true; non the less I want to to stick to the original version; This is due to the fact that the original question in mind was why the determinant of a knot always is an odd integer

Comment: @user8675309 -- great and intuitive answer! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Given a matrix $A_{2(n+1)\times 2(n+1)}\in \mathrm{Mat}(2(n+1)\times 2(n+1),\mathbb{Z})$ there is matrices
$$
\begin{array}{c c c}
A_{2n \times 2n}\in \mathrm{Mat}(2n\times 2n,\mathbb{Z}), 
& \quad &
B_{2n \times 2}\in \mathrm{Mat}(2n\times 2,\mathbb{Z}),
\\ && \\
C_{2 \times 2n}\in \mathrm{Mat}(2 \times 2n,\mathbb{Z}),
& \quad  &
D_{2\times 2} \in  \mathrm{Mat}(2 \times 2,\mathbb{Z})
\end{array}
$$
such that
$$
A_{2(n+1)\times 2(n+1)}
=
\left\lgroup
\begin{array}{cc}
A_{2n \times 2n}  & B_{2n\times 2}
\\
 C_{2 \times 2n } & D_{2 \times 2 }
\end{array}
\right \rgroup.
$$
Now you just use induction and the [formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix#Block_matrix_determinant)
$$
\det\begin{pmatrix}A & B \\ C & D\end{pmatrix} = \det(A) \det\left(D - C A^{-1} B\right).
$$
to proof that
$$
\det\big( A_{_{2(n+1)\times 2(n+1)}} + A_{_{2(n+1)\times 2(n+1)}}^T \big)
\\
=\det\begin{pmatrix}
A_{_{2n\times 2n}} + A_{_{2n\times 2n}}^{T} 
& 
B_{_{2n\times 2}}^{}+C_{_{2\times 2n}}^{T}
\\
C_{_{2\times 2n}}^{}+B_{_{2n\times 2}}^{T}
&
2 D_{_{2\times 2}}
\end{pmatrix}
\\
=\det
\begin{pmatrix}
A_{_{2n\times 2n}} + A_{_{2n\times 2n}}^{T} 
\end{pmatrix}
\det\Big(
2D_{_{2\times 2}} - (C_{_{2\times 2n}}^{}+B_{_{2n\times 2}}^{T})(A_{_{2n\times 2n}} + A_{_{2n\times 2n}}^{T})^{-1}(B_{_{2n\times 2}}^{}+C_{_{2\times 2n}}^{T}) 
\Big)
$$
is equal to $1$.

Comment: Please pardon my ignorance, this is not my area of expertise: Is $A_{2n \times 2n}$  the given matrix $A$? What are $B, C, D$? Is $A$ necessarily invertible?

Comment: @MartinR Yes, $A_{2n\times 2n}$ is a matrix of order $2n\times 2n$. Yes, $B$, $C$ and $D$ are matrices. Yes, $A$ is necessarily invertible.

Comment: $A$ is given, but what are $B, C, D$? And how does this lead to $\det(A-A^T)$ and $\det(A+A^T)$?